# Using Vector3 in code behind crashed Visual Studio XAML designer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app project using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I have a custom control that references Vector3 class to apply some shadow effect in code behind.

In another page where I use this custom control, the XAML designer crashes with the following error:

```
BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
```

The problem seems to only happen during design time. When I run the app everything works normally.

Removing the use of Vector3 object from my custom control's code behind solves the problem but it's not a good solution. The debug config for my project is x86.

Can you please advise on how can I avoid this crash?

Comment: Have you seen this document: [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.BadImageFormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Yes but it didn't seem to help. I tried switching from x32 to x64 and back again to refresh things but I still have the error. I can provide a sample project that reproduces the problem if this can help.

Comment: As a workaround, I put a guard clause that prevents problematic function from running during design time.

Comment: Yes, please provide a demo, thx.

Comment: I tried isolating the problem and reproducing it in a minimal uwp project. You can find it on my github repo here: https://github.com/disklosr/Vector3Issue

Comment: There's a similar issue logged here https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/112

Comment: Thanks I added reference to my repo for reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

For Visual Studio related feedback, please submit it to [Connect portal site](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio)

I've created a feedback for you in here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107712/method-not-found-exception-in-vs-xaml-designer

I fully understood this is not user-friendly. If it doesn't hinder your dev process, could you please comment that code and completed all UI things, then uncomment it later as a temporary solution :)